# `yes` in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

How do I include the hypen or dash character (`-`) as an argument to `yes` in Ubuntu?

In FreeBSD, I can do this:

```
$ yes "-tcp" | head -n 2
-tcp
-tcp
```

But in Ubuntu, I get an error:

```
$ yes "-tcp" | head -n 2
yes: invalid option -- 't'
Try `yes --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Did you try single quotes around -tcp?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response everyone!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
$ yes -- "-tcp" | head -n 2
```

The double-dash tells yes to stop parsing options.

Answer (score 5):

Use `yes -- -tcp`. The `--` will stop argument processing.

```
noufal@sanitarium% yes -- "-tcp" | head -n 2
-tcp
-tcp
```

Answer (score 3):

From `info yes`:

> To output an
>   argument that begins with `-', precede it with`--', e.g., `yes --
>   --help'

So you want:

```
yes -- -tcp | head -n 2
```